# SQLite3 foreign key mismatch

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a table called `id` with two primary keys, `id` and `host_id` and inserted data in them. I then created a table `listing_info` with a foreign key that references the `id` column in the table `id`. I run my queries and run into a foreign key mismatch error.

id table:

```
c1 = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS id (
    id INTEGER,
    host_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, host_id)
);
'''

c2 = '''
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO id
SELECT 
    id,
    host_id
FROM listings;
'''
```

listing_info table:

```
c1 = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS listing_info (
    id INTEGER,
    neighborhood TEXT,
    latitude REAL,
    longitude REAL,
    room_type TEXT,
    price REAL,
    security_deposit REAL,
    cleaning_fee REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES id(id)
);
'''

c2 = '''
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO listing_info
SELECT 
    id,
    neighbourhood,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    room_type,
    price,
    security_deposit,
    cleaning_fee
FROM listings;
'''
```

Why am I getting a foreign key mismatch?

Comment: Because your FK only references one column of the PK.

Comment: Does my FK have to reference multiple PK's?

Comment: It has to reference an entire primary key or unique key/index, yes. Read https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html